# accessing object from previous ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring

From the reference link: [How do you redirect to another URI and access an object from the previous modelAndView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6658075/944569), if the `public ModelAndView sendEmail() {}` had been modified and say, other objects like `Collection` or `HashMap` would have added in the Model Object, then how would you have accessed in the `/nextPageclass` method ?

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would just stick it into the HttpSession object:

```
    public ModelAndView something(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("name", "object");
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("nextPageclass"));
}
```

This should make the values available during the entire user's sessions rather than just on the individual page request.  You will end up having to manage the state of Session attributes but this provides a way to make the data available on the next page or any page thereafter without having to consistent get() and set() the value.